# Jupyter notebook does not start in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On MacOS Mojave 10.14.3 I have installed Anaconda 4.6.8 and created my own environment to run Tensorflow

```
conda update conda
conda create -n davide-tf python=3.7.0 anaconda
conda activate davide-tf

pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade ~/Downloads/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl
pip install pandas scikit-learn statsmodels matplotlib keras xgboost
```

When I open Anaconda Navigator and I select my `davide-tf` environment and try to launch Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6 the notebook does not start.

When I select the `base` environment, Jupyter Notebook starts as expected.

Can someone shed some light?

```
(base) mylaptop:~ bajd$ conda list -n base
# packages in environment at /ANACONDA/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py37_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0
appscript                 1.0.1            py37h1de35cc_1
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0
astroid                   2.1.0                    py37_0
astropy                   3.1              py37h1de35cc_0
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py37_0
attrs                     18.2.0           py37h28b3542_0
babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0
backports                 1.0                      py37_1
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py37_0
bitarray                  0.8.3            py37h1de35cc_0
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3                   py37_0
bleach                    3.0.2                    py37_0
blosc                     1.14.4               hd9629dc_0
bokeh                     1.0.2                    py37_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h1d22016_1
bzip2                     1.0.6                h1de35cc_5
ca-certificates           2019.3.9             hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.11.5           py37h6174b99_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1
click                     7.0                      py37_0
cloudpickle               0.6.1                    py37_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0
conda                     4.6.8                    py37_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.17.6                   py37_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-verify              3.1.1                    py37_0
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0
cryptography              2.4.2            py37ha12b0ac_0
curl                      7.63.0            ha441bb4_1000
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0
cython                    0.29.2           py37h0a44026_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37h1de35cc_1
dask                      1.0.0                    py37_0
dask-core                 1.0.0                    py37_0
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1
dbus                      1.13.2               h760590f_1
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1
distributed               1.25.1                   py37_0
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py37_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py37h1de35cc_2
filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1
flask-cors                3.0.7                    py37_0
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3
gevent                    1.3.7            py37h1de35cc_1
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0
glob2                     0.6                      py37_1
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h878fce3_3
hdf5                      1.10.2               hfa1e0ec_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1
idna                      2.8                      py37_0
imageio                   2.4.1                    py37_0
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py37_0
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
isort                     4.3.4                    py37_0
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0
jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0
jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py37_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
keyring                   17.0.0                   py37_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py37h0a44026_0
krb5                      1.16.1               hddcf347_7
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37h1de35cc_2
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5
libcurl                   7.63.0            h051b688_1000
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1
libedit                   3.1.20170329         hb402a30_2
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_0
libpng                    1.6.35               ha441bb4_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                ha12b0ac_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                hcb84e12_2
libxml2                   2.9.8                hab757c2_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               hb819dd2_0
llvmlite                  0.26.0           py37h8c7ce04_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hef8c89e_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2
markupsafe                1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0
matplotlib                3.0.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.0.3            py37hf043ca5_0    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0
mkl                       2019.1                      144
mkl-service               1.1.2            py37hfbe908c_5
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py37h27c97d8_0
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37h27c97d8_0
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py37_0
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py37h04f5b5a_1
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py37_1
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1
networkx                  2.2                      py37_1
nltk                      3.4                      py37_1
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2
notebook                  5.7.6                    py37_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.41.0           py37h6440ff4_0
numexpr                   2.6.8            py37h7413580_0
numpy                     1.15.4           py37hacdab7b_0
numpy-base                1.15.4           py37h6575580_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0
odo                       0.5.1                    py37_0
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0
openpyxl                  2.5.12                   py37_0
openssl                   1.1.1b               h1de35cc_1    conda-forge
packaging                 18.0                     py37_0
pandas                    0.23.4           py37h6440ff4_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             ha5e8f32_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0
partd                     0.3.9                    py37_0
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0
pcre                      8.42                 h378b8a2_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py37_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0
pillow                    5.3.0            py37hb68e598_0
pip                       18.1                     py37_0
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py37_1
pluggy                    0.8.0                    py37_0
ply                       3.11                     py37_0
prometheus_client         0.5.0                    py37_0
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                    py37_0
psutil                    5.4.8            py37h1de35cc_0
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0
py                        1.7.0                    py37_0
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37hd4eaf27_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py37_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37ha12b0ac_0
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py37_0
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0
pylint                    2.2.2                    py37_0
pyodbc                    4.0.25           py37h0a44026_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0
pyparsing                 2.3.0                    py37_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0
pytables                  3.4.4            py37h13cba08_0
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
python                    3.7.1                haf84260_7
python-dateutil           2.7.5                    py37_0
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6
python.app                1.2             py37h1de35cc_1200    conda-forge
pytz                      2018.7                   py37_0
pywavelets                1.0.1            py37h1d22016_0
pyyaml                    3.13             py37h1de35cc_0
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py37h1de35cc_0
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py37_0
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py37_0
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0
rope                      0.11.0                   py37_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0
scikit-image              0.14.1           py37h0a44026_0
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py37h27c97d8_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py37h1410ff5_2
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0
setuptools                40.6.3                   py37_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py37_0
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0
sphinx                    1.8.2                    py37_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1
spyder                    3.3.2                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py37_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.15           py37h1de35cc_0
sqlite                    3.26.0               ha441bb4_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h1d22016_0
sympy                     1.3                      py37_0
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0
toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0
tornado                   5.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0
tqdm                      4.28.1           py37h28b3542_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0
wheel                     0.32.3                   py37_0
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wrapt                     1.10.11          py37h1de35cc_2
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                    py37_0
xlwings                   0.15.1                   py37_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                h0a44026_1
zict                      0.1.3                    py37_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0


(davide-tf) mylaptop:~ bajd$ conda list -n davide-tf
# packages in environment at /ANACONDA/anaconda3/envs/davide-tf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
anaconda                  custom                   py37_0
appnope                   0.1.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6             h1de35cc_1002    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.3.9             hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3                   py37_1000    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 5.1.0           py37h24bf2e0_1002    conda-forge
ipython                   7.3.0            py37h24bf2e0_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.13.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10                       py_1    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.0.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_3    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             h6de7cb9_1006    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16            h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
markdown                  3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h1de35cc_1000    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1               h0a44026_1002    conda-forge
notebook                  5.7.6                    py37_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.0.2r               h1de35cc_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pandoc                    2.7.1                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.4                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.6.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pip                       19.0.3                   py37_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.6.0                 py37_1000    conda-forge
pygments                  2.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.14.11          py37h1de35cc_0    conda-forge
python                    3.7.0             h145921a_1006    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2018.9                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     18.0.1           py37h4cc6ddd_0    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  7.0               hcfe32e1_1001    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.20.3                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                40.8.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.26.0            h1765d9f_1001    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.8.1                 py37_1001    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.2                   py_1001    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             ha441bb4_1000    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.1            py37h1de35cc_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                 py37_1000    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.1                   pypi_0    pypi
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
xgboost                   0.82                     pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4             h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.2.5             h0a44026_1006    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h1de35cc_1004    conda-forge
```

Comment: Try `pip install jupyter` from the conda env.

Comment: I did and the problem remains.

Comment: Does running `conda list` in your `davide-tf` env show Jupyter?

Comment: It shows: `jupyter        1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            5.2.4                      py_3    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add the outputs of `conda list -n base` and `conda list -n davide-tf` in two separate code blocks? Formatting is not great in comments.

Comment: Also, I just realised: your comment shows you have `jupyter_client 5.2.4`, but your question says you're trying to invoke `Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6`...

Comment: Also, could you be experiencing the same bug as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55252159/7315159)?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I have added the output. The reason the versions now do not match is because I tried other versions, but the issue persists. This issue is different from the one mentioned in that question because in my case I do not even get a new browser window. The terminal which is supposed to start the process doesn't even launch.

Comment: It looks like your base version of jupyter is the conda-forge version, while your davide-tf version is the pypi version. Could you try completely wiping jupyer from davide-tf and installing the conda-forge version? Also, is it feasible for you to make an entirely new environment based on your base and use that instead of davide-tf?

Answer (score 0):

By running the following commands in the environment I was using, the problem was solved.

1. `conda install -n your_notebook_env nb_conda_kernels`
2. `conda install -n your_notebook_env ipykernel`